# Getting "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword" on deleting Record from multiple tables

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

I am trying to delete rows against `attendnt_N` using java but getting this exception `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword`. If anyone knows about its removal/solution please let me know. Here's my code:

```
ResultSet rss = stmt.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANCE, ATTENDANTS");
    System.out.println(attendnt_N);   //working fine
    int countd = 0;
        while(rss.next()){
            countd++;
            if(attendnt_N.equalsIgnoreCase(rss.getString(1))){
                String dell = ("(DELETE FROM ATTENDANCE, ATTENDANTS WHERE Attendant_Name ='" + attendnt_N + "')");
                //String del = ("(DELETE FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE Attendant_Name ='" + attendnt_N + "')");   
                //String dell = ("(DELETE FROM ATTENDANTS WHERE Attendant_Name ='" + attendnt_N + "')");
                //stmt.executeQuery(del);
                stmt.executeQuery(dell);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record against "+ attendnt_N +" is Deleted");
                System.out.println("Deleted");
            }           
        }
    if(countd == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record against "+ attendnt_N +" does not exist");
        System.out.println("Not Deleted");
        faceFrame.repaint();
        delBut.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: executeQuery is used for select statements thus the 'missing SELECT' error. use executeUpdate instead as @davidhxxx suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle only supports deleting from one table at a time, and I believe HQL also has this limitation.  So you should use two separate `DELETE` statements:

```
String del1 = ("DELETE FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE Attendant_Name ='" + attendnt_N + "'";
String del2 = ("DELETE FROM ATTENDANTS WHERE Attendant_Name ='" + attendnt_N + "'";
stmt.executeUpdate(dell);
stmt.executeUpdate(del2);
```

Comment: thanks... I tried.. but still getting the same exception... Is there any other way?

Comment: after you figure out which SQL to use, make sure to change to using bind variables, too (`prepareStatement`, `st.setString(1, attendnt_N)`).

Comment: @Thilo Using a prepared statement would only be necessary IMO if the parameters are directly coming from the client side, which may or may not be the case here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank You So Very Much... Now it is working... I didn't removed the outer brackets from the `del1` and `del2` queries before.. Now I removed 'em and it is working.. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: If the parameters come from user input, then bind variables are REALLY necessary to prevent SQL injection. But even for "safe" values, it helps with performance as it reduces query parsing and planning overhead and is easier on the server-side statement cache.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should suppress your commented sql queries  when your post, it makes the code harder to read.

Tim Biegeleisen is right. You should do only one delete by table but you also need to change the method used with your statement.
`stmt.executeQuery(dell)` is for selection query.
For updating, use rather `stmt.executeUpdate(dell)`
Look at the documentation :

**ResultSet executeQuery(String sql)**

> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet
>   object.

**int executeUpdate(String sql)**

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an
>   SQL DDL statement.

Comment: Strange... the exception is the same ?can you post the new version of the code in your question ? Don t edit code but add it at the end of the post.
We will find :)

Comment: I didn't removed the brackets from this query `"(DELETE FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE Attendant_Name ='" + attendnt_N + "')";` instead I removed the outer ones... now I removed 'em and it is working fine... Thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to perform the delete of records is already provided in the answer by user Tim Biegeleisen. While, the question does not shed much light about what your table structure is there is one potential performance glitch that you would run into:
m
The `SELECT` query that you are using will result in a [CROSS JOIN](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join). Hence the `SELECT` statement below should be changed to use a more restrictive join such as an INNER JOIN.

```
stmt.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANCE, ATTENDANTS");
```

should be replaced with something like

```
stmt.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANCE, ATTENDANTS WHERE ATTENDENCE.ATTENDANT_NAME = ATTENDANTS.ATTENDANT_NAME AND ATTENDANTS.ATTENDANT_NAME = 'attendant1'").
```

But this I think is unnecessary. Using Tim's technique you can efficiently delete the required records without much complications and performance implications.

Comment: I am using Tim's technique and I replaced `stmt.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANCE, ATTENDANTS");` with  `stmt.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANCE, ATTENDANTS WHERE ATTENDENCE.ATTENDANT_NAME = ATTENDANTS.ATTENDANT_NAME AND ATTENDANTS.ATTENDANT_NAME ='" + attendnt_N + "')");`  like you said but now I am getting this exception `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: @Mee Please read my response carefully. I have mentioned after providing the alternative that what you are doing is not really required. All you want to do is to delete the records from Attendance and Attendants where Attendant name matches some value. So instead of your logic you only need to execute Tim's queries. Also, the example I have typed here is without any IDE support and may miss some brackets. Please use an IDE like SQL developer to test the queries first for syntax and get a hang of the operations before placing it in java code